# Aggregate function MAX alongwith Merge Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Im new to neo4j and I am looking to seek help.
I have 2 entities named entity1 and entity2 and their relationship is defined (CEO) ,however I was successful to load the data and form the relationship using merge

confidence value | Entity1     | Entity2        | Relationship

---

0.884799964      |Jamie Dimon  | JPMorgan Chase |  CEO

0.884799964      |Jamie Dimon  | JPMorgan Chase |  CEO

0.380894504      |Jamie Dimon  | JPMorgan Chase |  CEO

My question :  the confidence value is 0.88 and 0.38 for Jamie Dimon , ***Now I want to display a single relationship between Jamie Dimon and JPMorgan which holds the maximum confidence value (0.88)***

With this query I was able to display 2 relationships with confidence value 0.88 and 0.38 instead of 3 relationships, but I want a single relationship which holds maximum confidence.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/result_is_of_neo4j_final1.csv' AS line
MERGE (e1:Entity1 {name: line.relation_first, e1_confidence: toFloat(line.entities_0_confidence)})
WITH line, e1
MERGE (e2:Entity2 {name : line.relation_second, e2_confidence: toFloat(line.entities_1_confidence)})
WITH e2, e1, line
MERGE (e1)-[r:IS_FROM {relation : line.relation_relation, r_confidence: toFloat(line.relation_confidence)}]->(e2)
RETURN e1,r,e2
```

Comment: So the relationship you want already exists in the graph, no need to create it. Do you want a query that will only return that single highest confidence relationship per relation type? Or do you want to only keep that highest confidence relationship per relation type, and delete the rest of the relationships with lower confidence?

Comment: I want to keep only the relationship with highest confidence at load. I do not want to query such relationship later. Is there any possibility??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much data are you planning to load this way? If it's a large import, it's likely you'll want to use PERIODIC COMMIT to speed up the import and avoid memory issues. However, doing so will also impact any kind of comparison and conditional logic in your import, as it's not guaranteed that the rows you need to compare are being executed within the same transaction.

I'd recommend importing all of your nodes and relationships without any extra logic, and then running a query after all the data is loaded to remove the unnecessary relationships.

This query should work for you after the graph is loaded. For every :IS_FROM relationship of a given relation, it will only keep the relationship with the highest r_confidence, and delete the others:

```
MATCH (e1:Entity1)-[r:IS_FROM]->(e2:Entity2)
WITH e1, r.relation as relation, COLLECT(r) as rels, MAX(r.r_confidence) as maxConfidence, e2
WHERE SIZE(rels) > 1
WITH FILTER(r in rels WHERE r.r_confidence <> maxConfidence) as toDelete
FOREACH (rel in toDelete | DELETE rel)
```

EDIT

If you need to get rid of duplicate relationships too, then an alternate approach that should work better might be to order your relationships of a specific relation between two nodes by confidence, and delete all except the first:

```
MATCH (e1:Entity1)-[r:IS_FROM]->(e2:Entity2)
WITH e1, r.relation as relation, r, e2
ORDER BY r.r_confidence DESC
// since we just sorted, the collection will be in order
WITH e1, relation, COLLECT(r) as rels, e2
// delete all other relationships except the top
FOREACH (rel in TAIL(rels) | DELETE rel)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, code works however it is giving all the relationship with high confidence, i.e Jamie dimon and JPMorgan has 2 links with conf value 0.88. i want to avoid this duplicate relationship. any workaround for this?? please let me know ..

Comment: Keep in mind the query distinguishes between relationships with different relation properties, so after the deletion, there may be multiple relationships between two nodes because they each have a different relation property. However, for eliminating duplicate relationships (same relation, same r_confidence), I added an alternate query that should do the trick.